# How to populate MySql db using hibernate?

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I am starting with Hibernate by going through this Sample. But this is the information in the debug console and I think it has something to do with the configuration file because when the configure() method is called it throws an exception.

```
debug:
Feb 24, 2015 11:53:50 AM  org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.4.Final}
Feb 24, 2015 11:53:50 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.1.Final}
Feb 24, 2015 11:53:50 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Feb 24, 2015 11:53:50 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Feb 24, 2015 11:53:51 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: hibernate.cfg.xml
Feb 24, 2015 11:53:51 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: hibernate.cfg.xml
Feb 24, 2015 11:53:51 AM org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver resolveEntity
WARN: HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace    http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
Feb 24, 2015 11:53:51 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: hibernate.hbm.xml
Feb 24, 2015 11:53:52 AM org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver resolveEntity
WARN: HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
Exception Thrown org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Unable to read XML
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at hellomain.main(hellomain.java:46)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 15 seconds)
```

Main file:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Session session = null;
    try
    {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

        configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
        ServiceRegistry sr = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
        SessionFactory sf = configuration.buildSessionFactory(sr);
        session = sf.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        System.out.println("Populating the Database.");
        Message message = new Message("Hello Vinodh");
        session.save(message);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        System.out.println("DOne");
    }catch(HibernateException e){
        throw e;
    }finally{
        session.flush();
        session.close();
    }

}
```

Confg File:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate    Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
<mapping resource="hibernate.hbm.xml"></mapping>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Mapping File:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="hello.Message" table="message">
        <id name="id" column="id" type="Long">
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id> 
        <property name="text">
            <column name="text"></column>  
        </property>    
   </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Unable to read xml is the exception thrown

Comment: org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Unable to read xml is the exception thrown

Comment: @Tiny I have edited the stack trace